# Михаил(,) как всегда(,) будет делать работу по-своему. Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Правило: *Слова «как всегда» не являются вводными и не обособляются, если они входят в состав сказуемого или тесно связаны с ним по смыслу.* Тот ли это случай или не тот?

Answer (score 1):

В середине предложения "как всегда" является вводным сочетанием и обособляется.
Не обособляется в том случае,если это союз +наречие. В этом случае оборот изъять нельзя. Вводное сочетание употребляется в значении: «по обыкновению, как обычно».

> Ср.: Несколько солдат, видимо, ничего не понимают, но, как всегда, в чем-то (вернее, во всем) сомневаются, подозрительно покачивают головами. **И.
>   Бунин, Окаянные дни.**

А как всегда в беде было принято бросаться к родне, то командир быстро счелся родней с адъютантом его величества Саблуковым и поскакал в Павловское. Ю. Тынянов, Подпоручик Киже. И Митя чувствовал и обостренную близость к Кате, – как всегда это чувствуешь в толпе к тому, кого любишь… И. Бунин, Митина любовь.

Вводное выражение «как всегда» можно изъять из состава предложения или переместить, а союз и наречие «как всегда» изъять или переместить невозможно. В тех случаях, когда различие между вводным выражением и обстоятельством неявное, решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста.

**Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.**